# Binary to decimal - prolog

Tags: binary, prolog, decimal, clpfd

I found this on stack:  [reversible "binary to number" predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192063/reversible-binary-to-number-predicate/27788081#27788081)

But I don't understand

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

binary_number(Bs0, N) :-
        reverse(Bs0, Bs),
        binary_number(Bs, 0, 0, N).

binary_number([], _, N, N).
binary_number([B|Bs], I0, N0, N) :-
        B in 0..1,
        N1 #= N0 + (2^I0)*B,
        I1 #= I0 + 1,
        binary_number(Bs, I1, N1, N).
```

Example queries:

```
?- binary_number([1,0,1], N).
N = 5.

?- binary_number(Bs, 5).
Bs = [1, 0, 1] .
```

Could somebody explain me the code

Especialy this : `binary_number([], _, N, N).` (The _ )

Also what does library(clpfd) do ?

And why     `reverse(Bs0, Bs)` ? I took it away it still works fine...

thx in advance

Comment: Try `binary_number([1,0,0], N)` to see that `reverse/2` is needed. For `library(clpfd)` look at [tag:clpfd]. There are simpler examples. `factorial/2` is  good start.

Comment: 1 ?- binary_number([1,0,1,1,0,0,1], L).
L = 77.

I did that why I don't understand what's its use.

Comment: Why do you look at more complex queries? Look at simpler ones.

Comment: I need to convert binary to decimal. And I found this so I try to understand. The easy stuffs with factorial I know how to do.

Beside one way to get better is to try hard stuffs

Comment: You did not understand the `factorial/2` example in clpfd. After all, you are asking "what does `library(clpfd)` do?" You would not ask this, would you have studied and understood `factorial/2` here on SO.

Comment: No what I said was that I understand factorial in prolog.

Never said I did with the clpfd....

But now I do thx by the way

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28442760/772868).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original, `binary_number([], _, N, N).`, the `_` means you don't care what the value of the variable is. If you used, `binary_number([], X, N, N).` (not caring what `X` is), Prolog would issue a singleton variable warning. Also, what this predicate clause says is that when the first argument is `[]` (the empty list), then the 3rd and 4th arguments are unified.

As explained in the comments, `use_module(library(clpfd))` causes Prolog to use the library for *Constraint Logic Programming over Finite Domains*. You can also find lots of good info on it via Google search of "prolog clpfd".

Normally, in Prolog, arithmetic expressions of comparison require that the expressions be fully instantiated:

```
X + Y =:= Z + 2.  % Requires X, Y, and Z to be instantiated
```

Prolog would evaluate and do the comparison and yield true or false. It would throw an error if any of these variables were not instantiated. Likewise, for assignment, the `is/2` predicate requires that the right hand side expression be fully evaluable with specific variables all instantiated:

```
Z is X + Y.  % Requires X and Y to be instantiated
```

Using CLPFD you can have Prolog "explore" solutions for you. And you can further specify what domain you'd like to restrict the variables to. So, you can say `X + Y #= Z + 2` and Prolog can enumerate possible solutions in `X`, `Y`, and `Z`.

As an aside, the original implementation could be refactored a little to avoid the exponentiation each time and to eliminate the `reverse`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

binary_number(Bin, N) :-
    binary_number(Bin, 0, N).

binary_number([], N, N).
binary_number([Bit|Bits], Acc, N) :-
    Bit in 0..1,
    Acc1 #= Acc*2 + Bit,
    binary_number(Bits, Acc1, N).
```

This works well for queries such as:

```
| ?- binary_number([1,0,1,0], N).

N = 10 ? ;

no
| ?- binary_number(B, 10).

B = [1,0,1,0] ? ;
B = [0,1,0,1,0] ? ;
B = [0,0,1,0,1,0] ? ;
...
```

But it has termination issues, as pointed out in the comments, for cases such as, `Bs = [1|_], N #=< 5, binary_number(Bs, N).` A [solution was presented by @false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28442760/772868) which simply modifies the above helps solve those termination issues. I'll reiterate that solution here for convenience:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

binary_number(Bits, N) :-
    binary_number_min(Bits, 0,N, N).

binary_number_min([], N,N, _M).
binary_number_min([Bit|Bits], N0,N, M) :-
    Bit in 0..1,
    N1 #= N0*2 + Bit,
    M #>= N1,
    binary_number_min(Bits, N1,N, M).
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your precision, and your time. You should be a teacher :)

Comment: Lots of termination problems. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28442760/772868)

Comment: @false thanks, I will indeed study that. My edit here was to take a clunky solution I posted before, which also had similar termination issues, and make it less clunky. But you're right: the termination issues remain.