# Constraint not propagated upon instantiation of list members

Tags: parsing, prolog, clpfd

I am building a parser and generator for dates and times. In an ordinary programming language these would be written separately. In Prolog+CLP(FD) I can write 1 predicate that does both :-)

In my use case it often makes sense to parse a number of digits and convert the to an integer, or to generate a number of digits based on a given integer.

My problem is that `clpfd:run_propagator/2` is not called when individual digits are instantiated, despite my declarations using `clpfd:init_propagator/2`. Is there a way to do this or am I making a mistake in my definition of `clpfd_digits/2`?

Code implemented in SWI-Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

:- multifile(clpfd:run_propagator/2).

day(D) --> {clpfd_digits(D, [D1,D2])}, digit(D1), digit(D2).

digit(D) --> [C], {code_type(C, digit(D))}.

clpfd_digits(N, Ds):-
  clpfd:make_propagator(clpfd_digits(N, Ds), Prop),
  clpfd:init_propagator(N, Prop),
  clpfd:init_propagator(Ds, Prop),
  forall(
    member(D, Ds),
    clpfd:init_propagator(D, Prop)
  ),
  clpfd:trigger_once(Prop).

clpfd:run_propagator(clpfd_digits(N, Ds), MState):-
  (   maplist(is_digit0, Ds)
  ->  clpfd:kill(MState),
      digits_to_nonneg(Ds, N)
  ;   integer(N)
  ->  clpfd:kill(MState),
      nonneg_to_digits(N, Ds)
  ;   true
  ).

digits_to_nonneg([], 0):- !.
digits_to_nonneg(Ds, N):-
  maplist(char_weight, Chars, Ds),
  number_chars(N, Chars).

char_weight(Char, D):-
  char_type(Char, digit(D)).

nonneg_to_digits(0, []):- !.
nonneg_to_digits(N, Ds):-
  atom_chars(N, Chars),
  maplist(char_weight, Chars, Ds).

is_digit0(D):- integer(D), between(0, 9, D).
```

Example of use:

```
?- string_codes("12", Cs), phrase(day(D), Cs).
Cs = [49, 50],
clpfd_digits(D, [1, 2]).
```

As you can see the constraint is not calculated to derive at the value of `D`.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28442760/772868) for the clpfd way to solve a related problem.

Comment: What do you expect to gain compared to `when((ground(Codes);nonvar(N)), number_codes(N,Codes))`? Both are weak and not relations - for that matter.

Comment: @false That comes quite close! However it does not deal with padding zeros, e.g., `phrase(day(2), "02")`.

Comment: I cannot see any problem with that goal, provided `set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes)`.

Comment: @false I meant `phrase(day(2), Codes)`, where `Codes` should comply to an ABNF rules that requires exactly two digits.

Comment: What I still miss is your statement what you actually expect. Do you expect this to work for dates only - then it would be trivial. But in the general case, infinity has to be considered... And will you refuse a date like 1.1.2015? It's all this undefinedness around which makes it difficult to answer.

Comment: Why not `day(N) --> digit(D1), digit(D2), {N #= 10*D1+D2, N in 0..31}.`

Comment: @false The parser should only succeed for days that consist of exactly two digits, e.g., `"02" -> 2`. The generator should only generate days that consist of exactly two digits, e.g., `2 -> "02"`. Here `"02"` stands for (a part of) the parsed/generated string and `2` stands for the value that is parsed / based on which a string is generated. In the overall grammar the values are compound terms `date/9` as per http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=dattimedata

Comment: The bug lies in code_type: It fails for: `code_type(C,digit(N)),N=0.` but succeeds for `N=0,  code_type(C,digit(N)).`

Comment: ... whereas same works for `N = 1`. So it's a SWI bug.

Comment: You do the reporting?

Comment: @false I agree to your use of `N #= 10*D1+D2 ...` for this particular case but that would only work for sequences of two digits. I would prefer it to be more generic, e.g., for use in anther rule which parses the number of days in the year, the year itself, and possibly other domains (e.g., social security numbers, telephone numbers) as well. For some uses it would be cumbersome to write `10000*D1+1000*D2+...`

Comment: @false Thanks for spotting the SWI bug! I will indeed report it.

Comment: This is what I suspected in the first place!You have not clearly stated how you want to handle infinity!

Comment: @false Ah, only now do I understand your remark about infinity properly :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 for using CLP(FD) constraints for this task!

`forall/2` and constraints do not mix very well, since backtracking revokes posted constraints.

Your example works as expected with:

`flip_init(Prop, D) :- clpfd:init_propagator(D, Prop).`

and using `maplist(flip_init(Prop), Ds)` instead of `forall/2`.

The next problem is then that `digits_to_nonneg([1,2], N)` simply fails, but this is unrelated to the actual constraint triggering, which happens as expected. (By the way: Using constraints, you may be able to simplify the code so that you can use a single predicate in both directions.)

Also, you can use `in/2` instead of `between/3`: `D in 0..9`. This is often useful if you want to use it as a constraint instead of just a test.

Comment: Did any one of the three upvotes actually **test** the resulting code? There are still many further errors in it. Like the two cuts.

Comment: I certainly didn't: After answering the actual question (*triggering* the propagator), I did not even attempt to correct the first mistake I found after that (`digits_to_nonneg/2` failing unexpectedly), much less even further beyond. Writing correct propagators is certainly worth several questions in its own right.