# How to parse a list and form a number in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I would like to know if someone could help me with a problem in prolog. I have to define two predicates but before that, I need to find out a way how to parse a list and form a number. For example [1,2,3] => 123. I tried different ways to do this but nothing works good. My code looks like this, I know it is not good but I can't find another way.

```
num([H|T],I,RI,RES):-
    H2 is H * I,
    R1 is RI + H2,
    I2 is I/10,
    RES2 is RES + R1,
    num(T,I2,R1,RES2).
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28442760/772868) works for binary numbers. So you need to adapt it for decimal numbers.

Comment: @false, good link (+1). I was going to add the CLPFD solution to my initial answer, but was oversimplifying for what I thought was the scope for the OP's problem. Ultimately, CLPFD is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Your hunch is correct that this can be much simpler. Recursively, you want to think of the digits `[A, B, C]` representing number as, `(((A * 10) + B) * 10) + C`.

To start, you want to think about what kind of predicate you desire. That would simply be, `num(Digits, Number).` which yields `Number` given `Digits`. You'll need an accumulator for intermediate results using the above formula concept, so your `num/2` needs to call a `num/3` that will include an accumulator argument that you carry along:

```
num(Digits, Num) :-
    num(Digits, 0, Num).    % Accumulator initially 0
```

If the input list is empty, the result is the accumulator:

```
num([], A, A).              % Result is accumulator when there are no digits
```

Then your recursive case:

```
num([D|T], A, R) :-
    NewA is (D * 10) + A,  % New accumulator is (current digit * 10) + old accumlator
    ...                    % Need recursive call
```

I'll leave the `...` for you to fill in as an exercise. :)